# Method does not execute when called. FIRESTORE

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method: **calcularPrecio()** , that is called when I click a button. That method has to update the price **( precio )** and set the text in a TextView. After that, I retrieve the text from outside the method from the same TextView and I put it in a batch to upload it to Firestore.

The problem is that the price is set in the batch before the method has finished, so I get the old price in the batch, and then, the Textiew updates.

I looked it with the debugger. It starts executing the method, then goes outside, and then returns to finish the method, and I don't know why!

This is the code of the button:

```
    mRealizarPedido = findViewById(R.id.pedido_boton_realizarPedido);
    mRealizarPedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         extra.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                extra.put("aprobado", false);
                calcularPrecio(editTextArray,nombres,posiciones);
                extra.put("precio", Integer.parseInt(mTextoPrecio.getText().toString()));
                Log.d("outside:  ", String.valueOf(extra.get("precio")));
                Barriles.put("Barriles",barriles);
                Botellas.put("Botellas",botellas);
                Monjitas.put("Monjitas",monjitas);                   
                mLote.set(refPedido , Barriles, SetOptions.merge());
                mLote.set(refPedido , Botellas, SetOptions.merge());
                mLote.set(refPedido , Monjitas, SetOptions.merge());

                //Cargo al lote informacion extra
                mLote.set(refPedido, extra, SetOptions.merge());



                //Subo el lote
                mPedidoProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mLote.commit().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        Toast.makeText(PedidoActivity.this, "Pedido Agregado",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(PedidoActivity.this, "Error agregando el pedido al servidor",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });

                // Bunch of code that is not relevant...


            }

        }
    });
```

And this is the method:

```
private void calcularPrecio(final EditText[] editTextArray, final String[] nombres, final List<Integer> posiciones) {

    mBaseDatos.collection("Precios").document("precios").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();

                if (doc != null) {

                    int precio = 0;
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());

                    for(int j=0; j<posiciones.size(); j++){

                        int i = posiciones.get(j);
                        int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(editTextArray[i].getText().toString());
                        String nombre = nombres[i];

                        if (i <= 8){

                            int p = (int) Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(doc.get("Barriles." + nombre)));
                            precio += cantidad * p;

                        } else if (8 < i && i <= 17){

                            int p = (int) Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(doc.get("Botella." + nombre)));

                            precio += cantidad * p;

                        }else{

                            int p = (int) Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(doc.get("Monjitas." + nombre)));
                            precio += cantidad * p;

                        }

                    }

                    mTextoPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(precio));

                    Log.d("inside:  ", String.valueOf(extra.get("precio")));

                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG, "No existe el documento");

                }

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "get fallo con la exepción: ", task.getException());

            }

        }
    });

}
```

If I run the code, in the Logcat I get first the output of:

```
Log.d("outside:  ", String.valueOf(extra.get("precio")));
```

And after the output of:

```
Log.d("inside:  ", String.valueOf(extra.get("precio")));
```

It should be the other way around! what I am missing? How do I get the updated price to upload to the batch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call method after execution of `onComplete` method of `OnCompleteListener` so Create one new Method called `updateDetails()` and call it after `Log.d("inside:  "`

```
public void updateDetails()
    {
     extra.put("precio", Integer.parseInt(mTextoPrecio.getText().toString()));

                Log.d("outside:  ", String.valueOf(extra.get("precio")));


                //Cargo las cervezas a los Mapa de datos generales
                Barriles.put("Barriles",barriles);
                Botellas.put("Botellas",botellas);
                Monjitas.put("Monjitas",monjitas);

                //Cargo en el lote todos los Mapas de datos
                mLote.set(refPedido , Barriles, SetOptions.merge());
                mLote.set(refPedido , Botellas, SetOptions.merge());
                mLote.set(refPedido , Monjitas, SetOptions.merge());

                //Cargo al lote informacion extra
                mLote.set(refPedido, extra, SetOptions.merge());



                //Subo el lote
                mPedidoProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mLote.commit().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        Toast.makeText(PedidoActivity.this, "Pedido Agregado",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(PedidoActivity.this, "Error agregando el pedido al servidor",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });

                // Bunch of code that is not relevant...
    }
```

Updated code

```
 //BOTON REALIZAR PEDIDO
    mRealizarPedido = findViewById(R.id.pedido_boton_realizarPedido);
    mRealizarPedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

               // Bunch of code that is not relevant...


                // esta aprobado o no , y el precio del pedido
                extra.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                extra.put("aprobado", false);

                calcularPrecio(editTextArray,nombres,posiciones);

            }

        }
    });
```

Updated `calcularPrecio`

```
private void calcularPrecio(final EditText[] editTextArray, final String[] nombres, final List<Integer> posiciones) {

    mBaseDatos.collection("Precios").document("precios").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                    Log.d("inside:  ", String.valueOf(extra.get("precio")));
                    updateDetails();

                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG, "No existe el documento");

                }

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "get fallo con la exepción: ", task.getException());

            }

        }
    });

}
```